# How do I use GridBagLayout

Tags: java

I have have a `JLabel`, a `JButton` and a `JTextField`; I need to put the `JLabel` in cell (0,0) from the `JFrame` origin and then put a `JTextField` (1,0) and finally put a `JButton` (0,1) on the second line. But, all my components are put in the same row and they start from left to right.

My code:

```
public static  void initializeFrame(){
  GridBagLayout layout  = new GridBagLayout();
  // set frame layout      
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Source Demo");
  frame.setSize(new Dimension(400,200));
  frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
  GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
  c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
  JPanel    topPanel = new JPanel();
  JLabel jlbempty = new JLabel("MacAddress");
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 0;
  c.ipadx = 30;
  c.ipady = 10;
  topPanel.add(jlbempty,c);
  JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
  c.gridx = 1;   
  c.gridy = 0;
  c.ipadx = 30;
  c.ipady = 10;
  topPanel.add(field1,c);
  field1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));
  JButton jb = new JButton("Generation Mac");
  c.gridx = 0;
  c.gridy = 1;
  c.ipadx = 30;
  c.ipady = 10; 
  layout.setConstraints( jb, c ); // set constraints
  topPanel.add(field1,c); 
  topPanel.add(jb,c);
  frame.add(topPanel);
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the things that I observed in your code.

- Set layout of the `topPanel` to `GridBagLayout`.
- You are calling `topPanel.add(field1, c);` two times.
- **Don't** use preferred size instead use relative size. Just hand over it to Layout manger to size the component.

---

Read more about [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more clarity and find the sample code as well.

Please read more about the other properties of [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html).

---

Here is the simplified code with inline comments.

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
// c.insets=new Insets(5,5,5,5);   // margin outside the panel

JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

JLabel jlbempty = new JLabel("MacAddress");
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
// c.weightx=0.25;     // width 25% for 1st column
topPanel.add(jlbempty, c);

JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
// c.weightx=0.75;     // width 75% for 2nd column
topPanel.add(field1, c);

JButton jb = new JButton("Generation Mac");
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 1;
//c.gridwidth = 2;    //SPAN to 2 columns if needed
// c.weightx=1.0;     // back to width 100%
topPanel.add(jb, c);
```